# How can I tell align-current to align multicolumn cells properly?

Tags: align, aquamacs

Can `align-current` also handle `multicolumn` cells properly?
IT does not in my case, you can see in the following example, that the 2 columns called "Col" are placed above cell "c" in the editor after `align-current`, but they would have to be placed above "e" and "f" :

### source-code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{12cm}{|p{3cm}|X|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  Long text & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{Very-verylong text} & Col & Col       \\
\hline
       a    & b                                       & c   & d & e & f \\ 
    \hline
        a   & b                                       & c   & d & e & f \\
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

### aligned source text in the editor (Aquamacs):

[image]

### pdflatex output

[image]

How can I solve that? I have large tables with many columns and many multicolumns in the headings and it is absolutely confusing if those headings are not in the right place!

*Remark*: I'm currently using `Aquamacs 2.5`, but I assume that this problem is not bound to `Aquamacs` as it also happens if I use `emacs`in the terminal and try the same thing.

Comment: The `align-` functions are agnostic to the major mode;  they simply rely on regexp and text. It does not know the latex syntax of multiple columns and does the alignment based on the `&` characters.